# Почему возникает ошибка в DataTables

Tags: datatable

Почему может возникать ошибка:

> jquery.dataTables.min.js:61 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'aDataSort' of undefined

параметры в php

```
        $grid_init = array(
        'ajax' => 'index.php?action=list&obj=agreement&view=json',
        "processing" => true,
        "serverSide" => true,
        "bFilter" => false,
        "stateSave" => true,
        "dom" => '<i><"#list-toolbar.hidden-xs"><t><lp>',
        "order" => array(3, 'asc')
    );
```

в js:

```
$('#main-list').dataTable({$grid_init});
```

Comment: как бы намекает на Cannot read property 'aDataSort' of undefined

Comment: которая нигде не используется

Comment: подобный вопрос уже задавался в английской версии - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28454203/jquery-datatables-cannot-read-property-adatasort-of-undefined